# Python turtle drawing a symbol

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle

win=turtle.Screen()

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.width(5)


#The vertical and horizontal lines 
t.left(90)
t.forward(70)
t.left(90)
t.forward(20)

t.left(90)
t.forward(60)
t.left(120)
t.forward(35)
t.backward(10)
t.penup()
t.home()

#first small box
t.pendown()
t.left(90)
t.forward(70)
for i in range(3):
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(20)

#second small box
for i in range(2):
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(20)

t.home()


win.exitonclick()
```

[image: My python turtle code drawing]

[image: The character that I want to draw]

> As you can see the character that I want to draw using python turtle has extended lines at the horizontal line on top and the slanted line below. How do I do that in my code?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `turtle.write` method to draw the character for the symbol:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.write("耳", font=("Arial", 50, "normal"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic, you navigate your turtle everywhere it needs to go.  I suggest you blow up the character on the screen to the same size as your drawing and compare widths and distances, and keep making corrections.

As far as the extended lines, you can always backup a little bit before you move forward, and overshoot going forward a little bit and then backup:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.width(10)

# vertical and horizontal lines
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(70)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.backward(5)
turtle.forward(35)
turtle.backward(5)

turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(60)
turtle.left(100)
turtle.backward(5)
turtle.forward(35)
turtle.backward(5)

# slanted line
turtle.left(80)
turtle.forward(35)

# small box in center
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(25)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(20)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(25)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]