# Turtle semi curve for loop

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am finished drawing the character but is there any way for me to shorten my code? Like a for loop since my character has 2 semi-curves.

```
def second_character():
        t.penup()
        t.goto(13,95)
        t.pendown()
        t.right(90)
        t.forward(40)
    
        #Starting from this part
        t.setheading(270)
        t.circle(-130,45) 
        t.penup()
        t.goto(13,95)
    
        t.pendown()
        t.setheading(270)
        t.circle(130,45)
```

The character that I am drawing:

[image: The character that I am drawing]

Answer (score 0):

How about rather than think like a computer and use loops, think like a caligrapher and draw this character without lifting the pen, without overwritting:

```
def second_character():
    t.penup()
    t.goto(15, 3)
    t.setheading(225)
    t.pendown()

    t.circle(-130, -45)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.left(90)
    t.circle(130, 45)
```

Which, given an existing pen width of 10, gives us:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just like [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65276450/python-turtle-drawing-a-symbol), can't you just use `turtle.write` to make the symbol?

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.write("又", font=("Arial", 50, "normal"))
```